# Saving settings in chrome extension across devices

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, synchronization, settings

In my current chrome extension, I have a popup that has settings for content a content script it uses.  I want to be able to save these user settings and have them synced up across devices (different browsers but same user).

I also have my extension connected to a server which has access to a database.  Should I create my own login system to save these settings across devices? Or is there a better way to approach this.

I found documentation on OAuth, but there is not much information on if the user tokens are permanent or not, or how effective this would be for the features I am looking for.

Comment: [`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync)

Comment: is chrome.storage.sync across all devices? or just local

Comment: All browsers on all devices as long you are logged into your Chrome account on them and enable sync, which is on by default.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is what I needed!